# Erro ao rodar comando PIP no Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, docker

Eu tenho um projeto em python que roda dentro de um Docker.

Quando a imagem (Build) é montado rele da um

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

mas quando ele executa o comando retorna um erro de conexão.

Dockerfile Completo

```
FROM python:3.5

ADD ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Erro:

```
docker-compose build

Building socket
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.5
 ---> e649f67bb435
Step 2/6 : ADD ./app /app
 ---> 92af2870125a
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
Removing intermediate container e08611d47e59
 ---> cfa7b0c4904f
Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in c84d2c2adc31
Removing intermediate container c84d2c2adc31
 ---> 8d23ccfe53ff
Step 5/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 8f02d2e43eee
Collecting Flask==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742caec50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742caeac8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742cae908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742caecf8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742cae668>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
ERROR: Service 'socket' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1ne)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742caeac8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742cae908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742caecf8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5742cae668>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
ERROR: Service 'socket' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: *Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.0*, não parece existir a versão 1.0.0 ([releases](https://github.com/pallets/flask/releases))

Comment: existe, mas isso acontece com qualquer pacote que for instalado

Comment: você já tentou atualizar a versão do Python para a python:3.6?

Comment: todas as versão, o problema esta na comunicação entre o pip no container e o servidor onde ele deve buscar os pacotes

Comment: Está usando algum repositório _pip_ diferente do padrão? O container está na rede _default_ do _docker_? A rede _default_ do docker tem acesso à internet - pelo erro o problema é DNS?

Comment: Estou usando tudo padão, tenho acesso normal a rede, apenas o comando pip não funciona, ja tentei outras imagens, ubuntu, debian e etc, mas todos estão com problema no pip, já até fiz um teste com projetos no GitHub já prontos mas dam o mesmo erro, e tambem tentei em maquinas diferentes na minha, no trabalho e em um servidor externo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver o problema,

Aqui na empresa usa NET e por padrão eles bloqueiam a maioria das portas, o que acontecia é que o PYP não fazia a comunicação pelo bloqueio da porta, 
solicitei o desbloqueio de todas as portas na NET e agora esta funcionando normalme